# NodeJs Console.log not outputting results

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api

Good Day,

I am having a difficulty with NodeJs/Javascript. The expected behavior is that `console.log` with output the name of apps on the Google Play Store that have 'read your contacts' in the permissions using the following library: https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper/

However, my `console.log` does not output anything at the end, seems that `apps[i].appId` is empty somehow. Here is my code:

```
gplay = require('google-play-scraper');

gplay.search({
    term: "horoscope",
    num: 40
}).then(function(apps) {

        for (i = 1; i <= apps.length; i++) {

            gplay.permissions({
                appId: apps[i].appId,
                short: true
            }).then(function(perm) {


                    for (a = 1; a <= perm.length; a++) {

                        if (perm[a] == 'read your contacts') {

                            console.log(apps[i].appId)

                        }


                    }


                }


            )
        }

    }
);
```

Comment: Have you tried console.logging your apps variable after ".then(function(apps) {"?

Comment: You can't put an asynchronous call in a for loop like that. Use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) instead

Comment: Yep, @PatrickHund beat me to it, use array map to create an array of promises and then use Promise.all(), keep in mind that a for loop can create closure issues if you're not carefull.

Comment: And also, please make a habit of using `let` and `const` for defining your variables (like `gplay`, `i` and `a`)

Comment: Thanks. Really appreciate your time into this. Was hoping for a more "spoon feeding" answer, as i am no dev, and certainly not a JS coder, as this is my first JS code i wrote.

Comment: It's not bad as a first attempt, keep at it!  I was trying to make a sandbox.io code example for you, but I couldn't get the `google-play-scraper` to work, even with the simplest example from their docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put an asynchronous call in a for loop like that. Create an array of promises and then use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait until all the calls to the API are done.

I've created a working program based on your code example. I've added explanations as inline comments:

```
// use 'const' to define gplay because it doesn't get reassigned
const gplay = require('google-play-scraper');

gplay.search({
    term: "horoscope",
    num: 40
}).then(function(apps) {

    // create an array to collect the calls to get permissions
    // use 'const' to define it because it doesn't get reassigned
    const getPermissions = [];

    // arrays are zero based, start with 0, not with 1
    // use 'let' to define 'i'
    for (let i = 0; i < apps.length; i++) {
        const appId = apps[i].appId;

        // fill the array with Promises, i.e. call objects
        // that get resolved with a result after a while
        getPermissions.push(
            gplay.permissions({
                appId: appId,
                short: true
            }).then(function (perm) {
                // we put our permissions in a result object
                // along with the app ID
                return {
                    appId: appId,
                    perm: perm
                }
            })
        );
    }

    // Wait until all the promises are resolved after the
    // Google Play API was called – we get an array of results
    Promise.all(getPermissions).then(function(results) {
        // iterate through the results array, get a result
        // object for each iteration
        for (let r = 0; r < results.length; r++) {
            const result = results[r];
            const appId = result.appId;
            const perm = result.perm;

            // arrays are zero based, start with 0, not with 1
            // use 'let' to define 'a'
            for (let a = 0; a < perm.length; a++) {
                // always use "===", never use "=="!
                if (perm[a] === 'read your contacts') {
                    console.log(appId)
                }
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Note the this is still “beginner code”, meaning it could be simplified using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), etc. I've left that out intentionally so it is easier to understand the code.

A more advanced version of the code:

```
const gplay = require('google-play-scraper');

gplay.search({
    term: "horoscope",
    num: 40
}).then(apps => {

    const getPermissions = apps.map(app => {
        const { appId } = app;
        return gplay.permissions({
            appId,
            short: true
        }).then(perm => ({
            appId,
            perm
        }))
    });

    Promise.all(getPermissions).then(results =>
        results.forEach(({ appId, perm }) =>
            perm.forEach(p =>
                p === 'read your contacts' && console.log(appId)
            )
        )
    )
});
```

Comment: Thank you Very Much! Really appreciate it. I had to use "node --use_strict" or else i would get an error, but it is working fine. Regards.